# Best practices of Header and Footer on PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am a newbie with PhoneGap (I am using Cordovar 2.5). I want to develop a simple application which have a tabbar at bottom and the header bar at top of screen. The footer and header can be customized easily.
I have tried to use [iOS-Tabbar-Plugin](https://github.com/AndiDog/phonegap-ios-tabbar-plugin) but it seems can't be customize the UI. I also tried to use jQueryMobile fixed toolbars, but they jump around when user focus into text input (and the soft keyboard shows).

This maybe a stupid question, but I wanna know what is the best practice of Header and Footer bar for phonegap app? Any recommend for me?

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is to look at [Ratchet](http://maker.github.io/ratchet/). Is is a minimalistic (yet powerful!) library that enables you to quickly develop iOS applications.

Answer (score 0):

have a look on [this](https://github.com/frequent/bartender/) for header footer bar